# "or if" logical operation in Lua

Tags: if-statement, lua

I'm in a situation where I have

```
if A and B and C then
X
end
```

Which if I understood it correctly,  means it will only execute X if all three conditions (A,B,and C) are met.

That's fine by itself,  But, I need/want it to at the same time also check something that's like an "or if" statement, that is.

if A and B and C [or if] A and D [or if] A and E then
X
End

Meaning I want it to execute X when A and B and C are met, or if A and D are met, or if A and E are met.  How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 5):

Simple:

```
if (A and B and C) or (A and D) or (A and E) then
    X
end
```

Comment: Even better: `if A and ((B and C) or D or E) then X end`